# Trying to load a sub form

Tags: vb.net

I'm making a button to show data when clicked, then change the text of the button to hide data, and I can't find a way to do that. I need help.

how can I make it load the Form1_Load again or make the program restart which will solve it.

Tried to do the show() function, and the showdiaglog too didn't work for me. Idk what i'm missing here

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form1

    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'AccountsC20DataSet.ProductMast' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.


    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try

            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source = OMAR;Initial Catalog=AccountsC20;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=ofamo;Password="
            con.Open()
            cmd.Connection = con



            Dim Selected = ListBox1.SelectedValue.ToString()

            cmd.CommandText = "Insert into SInvoice  Values('SIV-1',0,1," & Selected & ",5.000000,0.000000,'04/04/2019 13:39:44',4.000000,20.000000,'',0,1,1,1,1,'04/04/2019 13:39:44','',1.000000,1,0,'','b',0.000000,5,0.000000,20.000000,'Nos',1.000000,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',0,3,'SIV-',1,1,1,1,1,1,0.000000)"
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            cmd.CommandText = "Insert into SInvoice  Values('SIV-1',1,2," & Selected & ",4.000000,0.000000,'04/04/2019 13:39:44',8.000000,32.000000,'',0,1,1,1,1,'04/04/2019 13:39:44','',1.000000,1,1,'','b',0.000000,5,0.000000,32.000000,'Nos',1.000000,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',0,3,'SIV-',1,1,1,1,1,1,0.000000)"
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()


            cmd.CommandText = "Insert into IDetails Values ('SIV-1',5,'','',1)"
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            cmd.CommandText = " Insert into Modified (VoucherNo,VoucherDate,CustomerNo,LoginName,ExtraFieldIndex,ActualVoucherPrefix,ModificationType,ModificationDate,ModificationTime,code,name,mastertype) Values ('SIV-1','04/04/2019 13:39:44',5,'su',3,'SIV-','Add','04/04/2019','04/04/2019 13:40:54','','','')"
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            cmd.CommandText = "Insert into HFields Values('SIV-1',0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,'','','','','','','','','','',1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,-155,-155,-155,-155,-155,-155,-155,-155,-155,-155,-155,-155,-155,-155,-155,-155,-155,-155,-155,-155)"
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            cmd.CommandText = "Insert into ExtraFields Values('SIV-1',1,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000)"
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            cmd.CommandText = "Insert into ExtraFields Values('SIV-1',2,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000)"
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            cmd.CommandText = "Insert into PurchaseData Values('SIV-1','04/04/2019 13:39:44',5,'',1,20.000000,0.000000,0,'',1.000000,'N','Y','04/04/2019 13:39:44',1,1,1,1," & Selected & ",1,'',0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0)"
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            cmd.CommandText = "Insert into PurchaseData Values('SIV-1','04/04/2019 13:39:44'," & Selected & ",'',5,0.000000,20.000000,0,'',1.000000,'N','Y','04/04/2019 13:39:44',1,1,1,1," & Selected & ",1,'',0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0)"
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            cmd.CommandText = "Insert into PurchaseData Values('SIV-1','04/04/2019 13:39:44',5,'',1,32.000000,0.000000,0,'',1.000000,'N','Y','04/04/2019 13:39:44',1,1,1,1," & Selected & ",1,'',0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0)"
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            cmd.CommandText = "Insert into PurchaseData Values('SIV-1','04/04/2019 13:39:44'," & Selected & ",'',5,0.000000,32.000000,0,'',1.000000,'N','Y','04/04/2019 13:39:44',1,1,1,1," & Selected & ",1,'',0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0)"
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MessageBox.Show("Data Saved Successfully")


        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error while inserting record on table..." & ex.Message, "Insert Records")
        Finally

            con.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        If Me.Button2.Text = "Show Products" Then
            Me.ProductMastTableAdapter.Fill(Me.AccountsC20DataSet.ProductMast)
            Me.Button2.Text = "Hide"

        ElseIf Me.Button2.Text = "Hide" Then


        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Where do you declare `Me.AccountsC20DataSet.ProductMast`? **then change the text of the button to hide data** `Button2.Text = "Hide Data"`

Comment: Put what's in `Form.Load` in a method instead. Then you can call that method from wherever you want. Your code has many other issues.

Comment: in a separate file, I made a connection through dataset, which did it all for me. The data calling is correct there is not problem with, it shows data when clicking, but I just wanna hide it again, either by reloading the form, or by finding a way to hide the data and change the button text to show products again @JeremyThompson

Comment: So have you tried to hide the data? Some thing like `Me.ProductMastTableAdapter.Clear()`?

Comment: @JeremyThompson worked thanks so much